# Silverlight 4 - WebClient in a using statement

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, webclient, using

When using the WebClient class from a regular desktop app, I can use in using statement to ensure that the network resources are cleaned up :

```
using(Webclient wb = new WebClient())
{
}
```

In Silverlight however, I can't do that because WebClient is not IDisposable.

1) Why WebClient is not IDisposable in silverlight ?
2) Is there another way I can ensure that the network resources are cleaned up ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason silverlight WebClient does not implement IDisposable is because it only supports asynchronous operations.  Since you cannot properly enclose asynchronous operations within a using statement supporting using would be meaningless.

You can use the `CancelAsync`method to kill any outstanding operation that you no longer need.